# Using HtmlUnit/HttpUnit under GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, htmlunit

I'm trying to load the DOM of web pages in my application (running under Google App Engine),  using HtmlUnit, HttpUnit or any similar library.

Did anyone manage to do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlUnit 2.8 supports GAE according to the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [patch](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2962074&group_id=47038&atid=448269) being worked on to fill this need, though it's doubtful it will land in the next release(2.8)